How can I put VS Code Remote file links in notification messages?
I'm looking for a way to add a link to a file on a WSL file system on Windows (with VSCode workspace being a WSL folder). When I add a link to a VSCode information message like so
window.showInformationMessage(
    'Some text with [LINK](file:///home/user/test.txt)');

VSCode will look for the file in the native file system (i.e., Windows, instead of WSL).
I can successfully open the right file in the WSL file system by running the vscode.open commmand like so
await commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', Uri.parse("file:///home/user/test.txt"));

However, when I try to add a command link to the notification message, it tries to open it on the Windows file system again:
window.showInformationMessage(
    `Some text with [LINK](command:vscode.open?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify("file:///home/user/test.txt"))}).`);

Is there another way of adding a file link to an information message, or is this just impossible at the moment?
